# bar_plot ggplot: conflict between values on bar and x axis label

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm struggling with my code to create a barplot with ggplot2 in which I try to add `y` values on top of the bars, but without moving the labels of the `x` axis.
`geom_text` works great to add values on the bars, but then I cannot adjust the `x` axis labels properly when rotated by 45˚ (i.e. the last letter of the label sticked to the axis).

My data

```
 dput(graph)
structure(list(x = structure(1:9, .Label = c("AAAAAAAAAAAAA", 
"BBBBBBBB", "CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC", "DDDDD", "EEEEEEEE", "FFFFFFF", 
"GGGGGGGGGGGGGGG", "HHHHHHHHHHHHHH", "IIIII"), class = "factor"), 
    y = c(1L, 5L, 10L, 1000L, 20L, 15L, 45L, 30L, 35L)), .Names = c("x", 
"y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

My code:

```
graph <- read.table("input.txt",header=T,sep=";")
output <- ggplot(graph,aes(x=x,y=y))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity")+
    geom_text(aes(label=y,y=(y+25)))+
    scale_x_discrete()+
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,max(50 + graph$y)))+
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45,vjust=0))
print(output)
```

I cannot post an image of the output, but the plot looks fine except the tick marks of the `x` axis fit to the middle of the `x` labels instead of the last letter of the label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add `hjust=1` to `axis.text.x=` and change `vjust=0` to `vjust=1`. To change appearance of bars you can try to use transformation of y values, for example, square root, with `scale_y_sqrt()`. Only positions for `geom_text()` should be adjusted.

```
output <- ggplot(graph,aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  geom_text(aes(label=y,y=(y+c(10,10,10,50,10,10,10,10,10))))+
  scale_y_sqrt(limits=c(0,max(50 + graph$y)),breaks=c(10,100,250,500,1000))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45,vjust=1,hjust=1))
output
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly that, thanks a lot ! I should ask that in another thread maybe, but I'm wondering if it is possible to insert a break in a bar (and thus the y axis) which is obviously bigger than all the other, in order to have a better display of the minor y values. Example here: hiding the "DDDDD" bar from maybe 50 to 900 and use a bigger y axis scale to make al the other bars bigger ?

Answer (score 1):

Here a ggplot2-like lattice version:

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
barchart(y~x, data=dat,
         scales = list(x = list(rot=45,cex=1.5)),
         par.settings = ggplot2like(), axis = axis.grid,
         panel=function(x,y,...){
           panel.barchart(x,y,...)
           panel.text(x,y,label=y,col='red',
                      adj=c(0.5,-0.5),cex=2)
         })
```

[image]

**EDIT**

To decrease differences between bars levels , one idea here is to use log scale:

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
barchart(y~x, data=dat,
         scales = list(x = list(rot=45,cex=1.5),
                       y = list(log=10)),
         par.settings = ggplot2like(), axis = axis.grid,
         yscale.components = yscale.components.log10ticks,
         panel=function(x,y,...){
           panel.barchart(x,y,...)
           panel.text(x,y,label=10^y,col='red',
                      adj=c(0.5,-0.5),cex=2)
         })
```

[image]

Comment: Log scales don't make much sense for bar charts because the bar goes to 0